# (gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm using Google Cloud for the first time and I'm trying to upload a test file to my root folder on my instance.  However, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value '[ua2r-website]'. Values must match the following regular expression: '[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?'
```

I'm in the path for that file.  Here's my command:

```
gcloud compute scp [testtext.txt] [ua2r-website]:~/
```

I've double-checked the spelling and the punctuation of the VM instance, and I can't find a difference.

Comment: Try dropping the square brackets.

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thank You!!! obviously it must be common knowledge that you leave out the square when you're doing it for real!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use gcloud auth login
gcloud auth login - authorize gcloud to access the Cloud Platform with Google user credentials

write the command

```
gcloud auth login
```

then you will get a link to click on from GCP. you will get a code from the link , copy it back to the VM. then you will be authorized to do the operation. 
Here is more details

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ['s and ]'s

gcloud compute scp testtext.txt ua2r-website:~/

Answer (score 0):

You can also drag and drop the files from your local computer filesystem to the open unix shell of your where your project is.